# CoffeeScript/Backbone/Marionette - tutorial example conversion and scoping issues

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm trying to create a basic version of this example in CoffeeScript: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2012/04/15/a-simple-backbone-marionette-tutorial/.  All the dependencies are declared as .coffee files in the order I write them (in the body), and jQuery + Underscore + Backbone + Marionette are in the head.

I have a model, **thing.coffee**

```
$ ->

  console.log 'load model'

  class Thing extends Backbone.Model

    defaults:
      myValue: null

   initialize: ->
     console.log 'new thing'

  window.Thing = Thing
```

My first hiccup is with scoping: if I don't declare `window.Thing`, the next file (the collection of `Things`, can't find the model `Thing`, and so on. What am I doing wrong there?

I have a collection, **things.coffee**

```
$ ->

  console.log 'load collection'

  class Things extends Backbone.Collection

    model: Thing

  window.Things = Things
```

I have a Marionette view, **thing_view.coffee**

```
$ ->

  console.log 'load composite model view'

  ThingView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend(
    template: '#template-thing'
    tagName: 'tr'
  )

  window.ThingView = ThingView
```

I have a Marionette view, **things_view.coffee**

```
$ ->

  console.log 'load composite collection view'

  ThingsView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend(
    tagName:  'table'
    id: 'things'
    template: '#template-things'
    itemView: ThingView
    appendHtml: (collectionView, itemView) ->
      collectionView.$('tbody').append itemView.el
  )

  window.ThingsView = ThingsView
```

I have an application **myapp.coffee**

```
$ ->

  console.log 'load app'

  # Load default data
  thingsCollection = new Things([ 
    new Thing(myValue: 'uno'), 
    new Thing(myValue: 'dos')
  ])

  data:
    thingsCollection: thingsCollection

  # Create application, specify default layouts
  MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application()
  MyApp.addRegions singleRegion: '#content'

  # On application init...
  MyApp.addInitializer (data) ->
    console.log 'Init application...'
    thingsView = new ThingsView(collection: data.thingsCollection)
    MyApp.singleRegion.show data.thingsView

  # Start application
  MyApp.start data
```

My html file looks like:

```
<div id="content">
    <script type="text/template" id="template-things">
       <thead>
          <tr class='header'>
             <th>myValue</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="template-thing">
       <td><%= myValue %></td>
    </script>
</div>
```

Following the `console.log`:

```
load model
load collection
load composite model view
composite collection view
load app
Init application...
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'render' of undefined
```

So, needless to say I'm confused as to what is going on - I'm sure theres tons of things wrong here, so please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I don't declare `window.Thing`, the next file (the collection of `Things`, can't find the model `Thing`, and so on. What am I doing wrong there?

The CoffeeScript compiler wraps each file in a self-executing function so `Thing` is local to the wrapper unless you forcibly globalize it by putting it in `window`.

I think your real problem is right here:

```
MyApp.addInitializer (data) ->
  console.log 'Init application...'
  thingsView = new ThingsView(collection: data.thingsCollection)
  MyApp.singleRegion.show data.thingsView
```

You create a `ThingsView` and store it in `thingsView`. But then you try to pass `data.thingsView` to `MyApp.singleRegion.show` but there's nothing in `data.thingsView` so you get a complaint when something inside Marionette tries to `view.render()`. I think you want this:

```
  thingsView = new ThingsView(collection: data.thingsCollection)
  MyApp.singleRegion.show thingsView
```

or this:

```
  data.thingsView = new ThingsView(collection: data.thingsCollection)
  MyApp.singleRegion.show data.thingsView
```

depending on what this `data` object is all about.

Comment: Thanks - I knew why window worked, but wasn't sure of why Backbone didn't just create a global namespace for the model automatically...guess it doesn't work like that!  

Looking at your example, it's obviously clear now -- I think there were too many references to "cats" in the example, and my js2coffee comprehension got lost :)

Answer (score 4):

The `window.Thing` thing is a byproduct of Coffeescript’s global namespace pollution avoidance. The idiomatic way of getting around that is to [use an `App` namespace](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#namespace_convention).

Initialising your classes only on DOM load is a [Backbone anti-pattern](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#abuse). If you namespace your classes, then you just have to ensure you load them in the right order (item view before collection view) and they can be created immediately instead of after the page has loaded.

Can you give us an idea of where the `Uncaught TypeError` is happening?